# documentation for Camel Exchange getContext() looking for documentation of what is available to call on exchange.getContext()

Tags: apache-camel, documentation

I'm trying to write a simple camel class to just retrieve the existing camel routes in the context.
then use those routes identified in context to start thru a JChannel/JGroups/Controlbus mechasim to start and stop the routes.

I am stumped because I can't find documentation supporting the exchange. such as getContext() - what can be called on getContext()???  I've found thru some examples a getRouteDefinition() and getOutputs() methods but, ... these methods return different Types, I don't know how to use or convert type, and the getRouteStatus() method requires a string input.

Answer (score 2):

The `exchange.getContext()` call returns `org.apache.camel.CamelContext`

Official API documentation for the `CamelContext`: https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.21.1/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html